# Pegar valores separados por espaços em Java

Tags: java, string

Alguém poderia me explicar como eu posso pegar valores separados por espaços em Java?

Por exemplo, o usuário informa tudo de uma vez os seguintes valores: `1 2 3` e tenho que colocar cada valor em uma variável.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pode separar usando o método `split()` da classe String:

```
public class SplitString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String valores = "1 2 3";
        String[] arrayValores = valores.split(" ");
        for (String s: arrayValores) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> 1
>   2
>   3

O `split()` transformará a String em um *array* de Strings, sendo que a separação dos elementos é dada pelo espaço que for encontrado no texto da String. PS: o espaço não fará parte de nenhum dos elementos do *array*, ele é considerado apenas como delimitador dos elementos e é descartado após o `split()`.

O `for (String s: arrayValores)` é o que se conhece como "`for` avançado", ele percorre cada elemento do *array* e o associa à variável `s`. Seria similar a fazer:

```
for (int i=0; i < arrayValores.length; i++) {
    String s = arrayValores[i];
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Porém de uma forma que se escreve menos para obter o resultado desejado.

Comment: Ótima resposta, só mais uma coisinha, poderia me explicar o que faz e como funciona este for? Sou iniciante, e só tinha me deparado com for's deste tipo "for (int i = 0; i > x; i++)".

Comment: Editei minha resposta, veja se ajudou.

Comment: Obrigado tirou minha dúvida.